# Password entry: are "paste from password manager" and "eyeball to view passwords" mutually-exclusive features?

Tags: passwords, password-policy, nist, sp800-63b

## Context

NIST SP 800-63b gives the following guidance for password forms (aka login pages):

> Verifiers SHOULD permit claimants to use “paste” functionality when entering a memorized secret. This facilitates the use of password managers, which are widely used and in many cases increase the likelihood that users will choose stronger memorized secrets.

> In order to assist the claimant in successfully entering a memorized secret, the verifier SHOULD offer an option to display the secret — rather than a series of dots or asterisks — until it is entered. This allows the claimant to verify their entry if they are in a location where their screen is unlikely to be observed. The verifier MAY also permit the user’s device to display individual entered characters for a short time after each character is typed to verify correct entry. This is particularly applicable on mobile devices.

## Question

I had the argument made to me that these two features should not be implemented together because they would allow a user to circumvent a password manager's protection and view the auto-populated password. I suspect this argument won't hold water, but I'm curious about community opinions.

Comment: I suspect that with most (all?) password managers, if you're logged in enough that it will paste passwords, then you're also logged in enough to go view the password.

Comment: Some password managers do have options to allow certain viewers to use a password but not see it. But as you show in your answer, it's a fairly thin protection. Doesn't even make sense if you aren't using browser plug-in, because you could just paste it into Notepad.

Comment: Additionally, if someone had access to input the password but not directly read it, they could read the contents with dev tools regardless of whether it's visible normally.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**Password managers are not meant to hide your passwords from yourself**

It's as simple as that. To whit: most password managers let you view your own password anytime you want anyway. I say "most" only because I haven't used them all. I've worked with a few sites where auto fill doesn't work for reasons outside the password managers control. Therefore viewing/copying your own passwords is a necessity.  IMO a password manager that doesn't let you view your own secrets is a broken password manager.

If you can use the password manager to view your own password, then an individual site that refuses to display a password at the user's request in an attempt to hide their password from themselves has *grossly* missed the bigger picture.

**Some people use password managers, some don't**

The ability to paste is very helpful when using password managers. The ability to view as you type is helpful for people who are typing their passwords (especially on phones). These are two different features for two different groups of people, both of whom can be expected to use a given site. Therefore to say you only need one of these features at a time is just silly...

Comment: I use a VDI environment where you cannot paste anything. And all of my passwords are managed by the password manager. If I could not see them, I would dump that manager and get a properly working one.

Comment: My password manager (LastPass, KeePass) hides the passwords from me in everyday use. It just fills them in. No need to see them, unless I explicitly want to do that. With LastPass I also need to enter the master password to see it. I like that.

Comment: @Marcel But you can just fill the password somewhere that lets you see it, like a browser or text file, right? Does requiring a master password to see it directly add any security?

Comment: @Mark to clarify, there is an "autofill" capability in browsers for password managers that have browser extensions.  This means, for instance, that if I go to example.com and have a username/password stored for it, the extension will fill in my username/password on the website automatically without me having to do anything.  Therefore to login I just have to hit the "Submit" button on the login form.  Therefore this particular functionality will only work for browsers.

Comment: Your second question is very relevant: does requiring your master password to see it add any security?  For most people probably not.  Such a feature would protect you against someone sitting down at your computer when you are away and manually copying all your passwords.  I doubt that is a relevant concern for most, and it's also not really the threat model that password managers are meant to protect against.  Therefore, for me personally, I'd quickly get tired of having to enter my master password all the time and would find a new password manager.

Comment: @ConorMancone You can get the password from the browser without your master password though (as the other answer shows), but I'll grant it'd increase the effort and knowledge needed.

Comment: @Mark indeed.  However, There is some "threat" mitigation by requiring a master password to view passwords. Without it someone could go through and copy passwords out of the manager en-masse. It would take a lot longer to launch sites and extract them individually. Again, I'm not saying that requiring the master password to view passwords is a *good* choice. It is an inconvenience to the legitimate user and a poor security control. However, it does do have some value, even if not worth it for most users.

Comment: @Marcel I use LastPass and the master password unlocks both using and viewing passwords at the same time. (Meaning if I get logged out then obviously I have to enter my password to use it). If I can have it fill a password then I can view the password. Maybe it depends how you've set it up?

Comment: @Kat Indeed, somehow I missed that.  I use Lastpass and once I have unlocked my vault I can view/copy passwords out anytime without having to re-enter my master password.

Comment: @Kat Yes it depends. Since I almost never feel the need to see my passwords anyway, I set it up to require the master password to do so. I can not find the setting right now however.

Comment: you might want to mention the security hole of a "text editor".  If the password is on the clipboard, they could have pasted it into a normal text edit field instead of a password field to see the password.  Not only is the OP's thought wrongheaded, it is also useless for the intended purpose.

Comment: That sounds like basic nonsense. Of course "paste from password manager” and “eyeball to view passwords” aren't mutually-exclusive and how could that matter?"

How could any ability to "paste from password manager” not mean that once Scummy Hacker has cracked password manager, all is lost?

Answer (score 30):

*[self-answer]*

You can trivially unmask a password field with right-click > Inspect Element > change `type="password"` to `type=""`. So there's really no reason *not* to put a "View your password" eyeball on a web UI.

Testing on GitHub's front page, which does not have the eyeball button:

[image: Unmasking a password with Inspect Element]

---

[image: Unmasking a password with Inspect Element]

Comment: Right. I was about to say that. The only good it does is keep non-tech-savvy users from unveiling the password, I guess?

Comment: @FireQuacker the dots are to prevent shoulder surfers, not to prevent any user from knowing their password.

Comment: Not only shoulder surfers. Consider a web conference with shared screen ...

Comment: A password manager could prevent filling fields that are not `type="password"`, e.g., when it has a deep browser integration, but you probably could still read the password from the developer console. The protection is to help you to prevent others from seeing your passwords and not to prevent you from seeing your own passwords, so I would not overthink it and just quickly login after the password is inserted by the password manager, so other people cannot get it when you leave your computer unlocked and unattended.

Comment: A password manager with deep browser integration has to trust the browser isn't doing anything it shouldn't. Luckily web browsers have an excellant security track record

Comment: @JCRM even without deep integration (or password managers themselves), the *user* still has to trust the browser to not steal passwords.

Comment: Oh man, I totally had to borrow this trick recently, lol!

Answer (score 20):

There are [many](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/237569/98538) [good](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/237570/98538) answers already, but I would like to add one point.

Quite frequently, I have to enter passwords on computers that I don't have my password manager installed on. When that happends, I read the password on my cell phone and enter it on the computer. This would also frequently be the case for those who uses a local password manager on just one device.

When entering random gibberish, it is very easy to get lost. Erasing everything and starting over is pain in the butt. If I didn't have the ability to view the password while typing it so I can easily correct mistakes, I would be lazy and pick much shorter passwords.

TL;RD: Allowing to view passwords while typing makes me pick better passwords, even if I am using a password manager.

Answer (score 12):

Consider that your first quote explicitly references *"paste"* functionality, which implies a clipboard. As opposed to autofill that directly enters data into a webpage form.

Common clipboard implementations do not prevent the user from pasting the clipboard contents into arbitrary destinations (or, indeed, other programs from retrieving/logging clipboard contents).

If the argument is that the "eyeball" functionality may reveal passwords to the user, the user could more easily do so simply by pasting the clipboard contents into a different non-masked field.

Comment: But asinine paste-blocking JavaScript often _doesn't_ distinguish between clipboard pastes and password-manager inserts.

Comment: Pasting the content into non-masked fields *or* just pasting it into a different program all together

Comment: Speaking of asinine paste-blocking JavaScript, if a site disallows pasting into the password box, then I'll echo all of the "find another password manager" comments and say "find another site".

Answer (score 8):

I would say that these requirements do not compete nor are mutually exclusive.

The only thing what must made sure is, that pasting the password does not trigger the "show last character" for the entire password. Instead, when pasting, the system should make sure, that only the dots (or any other visual cue, if any at all) are visible.

So:

- when pasting, the password is hidden completely during paste
- when entering by keys, the last character is shown for each keystroke

As others pointed out, AFTER pasting or keying in, the entirety of the password MIGHT get inspected either by F12 or the "eye" icon.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers: any password manager worth using uses a Master Password that needs to be entered before any passwords can be copied over. If you know that master password, the password manager allows you to see everything, even if you have to paste it in Notepad first. If you don't know that password, the password manager won't do anything with your passwords: it won't decrypt them, it won't autopopulate them, it won't allow you to paste them, it won't allow you to circumvent the protection of that master password in any way.

So if you don't know that master password, there is no way to get the passwords out of the vault (unless the password manager has a vulnerability). If you know the master password, you already have full access to the passwords in the password manager and there is no reason at all to try and circumvent security measures that aren't there.